# Copy and paste between Mac and headless linux VM

Tags: macos, vmware

I'm running VMWare Fusion on an OSX host machine.  I have a redhat VM installed, along with VMWare tools.  My VM is headless, meaning I just have the terminal (no graphical interface of any kind).  Is there any way I can copy from my host machine and paste into my VM?  All of the tutorials and questions on the topic seem to focus on doing this when you're running a GUI in your VM which isn't very useful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you SSH into the Redhat VM you'll be able to copy and paste the commands into your terminal window. Simple open terminal and type:

```
ssh yourRedhatUser@redhatIPaddress
```